# Do I need `kube-proxy` to use `Ingress` for load distribution?

Tags: kubernetes

Do I need `kube-proxy` to use `Ingress` for load distribution? Or do you get the `endpoint` and distribute it directly to the `pod` and use `kube-proxy` only when using `Load Balancer` and `nodeport`?

If so, then when you use `Ingress` for load distribution, it only takes care of the load from  `routes` to  `service`, and the load from  `service` to  `pod` is still done through `kube-proxy`. Is this the right understanding?

If not, what is the mechanism?

I'm a newbie to `K8s`, so if there is something wrong with my question itself, or with my understanding, please point it out, thank you very much!

I've looked up some information and it says that `Ingress` does not use `kube-proxy` to do the load.

I'm skeptical, I'd like to know why it doesn't use it and how it implements the `kube-proxy` part of the functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Ingress is just an API it actually depends on the implementation.

For example the traefik proxy ingress implementation is making loadbalancing over the endpoints it queries from the kubernetes API server. In that case the kube-proxy is not used.

Keep in mind: kube-proxy usually configures DNAT rules in iptables, so it is not a user space proxy and connections to the Service IPs are loadbalanced by the kernel and iptables.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem, I know very little about `kebu-proxy`, I need to understand it. best wishes